# prototype property on Object Constructor

Tags: javascript, object, properties, constructor, prototype

I know this Question might have been asked already in different ways on stackoverflow but still
I just need to clarify my doubt
There is one prop in Object Constructor namely prototype.
And there is Object.prototype Object.
So when i am writing something as `Object.prototype=object2`
Am I setting the prototype property on the Object Constructor or Object.prototype Object is getting the values from object2 by reference.

Comment: Please post your code, I don't understand a thing...

Comment: @elclanrs- There is no code .Its a general question.there could be problem with in language but the question clear in my mind.

Comment: I'm not realy sure what the question is either but here you can find some detail about what prototype is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711 The constructor property should point to the function that constructed the object instance `var anObject=new Object();anObject.constructor === Object;//true var anotherObject=new anObject.constructor()`

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the prototype of `Object` to `object2`, by reference.

```
var dogProto = {
  bark: 'woof'
};

// Define a Dog class
var Dog = (function() {});

// Set its prototype to that which is contained in proto
Dog.prototype = dogProto;

// Make a Dog
var fido = new Dog;

// What's the bark property of fido?
console.log(fido.bark); // outputs: woof

// Modify the original dogProto object
dogProto.bark = dogProto.bark.toUpperCase();

// What's the bark property of fido now?
console.log(fido.bark); // outputs: WOOF
```

Comment: It is written in Javascript. Copy and paste the code into this to watch it run: http://repl.it/languages/JavaScript

Comment: Setting prototype of Dog in this way will have `fido.constructor` point to `Object()` instead of `Dog` `Dog.prototype.bark="woof"` would be saver if you want to use constructor at some point. Like `Dog.prototype.haveAKid=function(){return new this.constructor();}`